# Why ContextLoaderListener is to be registered after Log4jConfigListener

Tags: java, spring

As per Spring Doc API http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html -

This (ContextLoaderListener) listener should be registered after Log4jConfigListener in web.xml

I am not getting why Log4jConfigListener is to be registered first?

Answer (score 5):

The documentation does not dive into details regarding their stated preference for this order.  I would assume this order is recommended so that logging is property configured prior to registration of the `ContextLoaderListener`, which would allow debug messages to be logged appropriately during registration.

Answer (score 1):

When using a custom log4j configuration (per application log4j-app.xml for instance) this needs to be bootstrapped BEFORE anything else. If not log4j will be bootstrapped using the global log4j.xml (or defaults) instead of the custom file.

The ContextLoaderListener (or many other classes) will trigger bootstrapping log4j, in which case you could endup with a different configuration as you expected. Also with an added risk of the `Log4jConfigListener` at application shutdown trying to destroy/close the global log4j system... (This can be the case if you don't ship log4j in your app but rely on your app-servers shipped log4j version).